# variable undefined in ansible playbook with group_vars/all.yml

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I'm trying to set the `hosts` value in a ansible playbook dynamically. This means that in the `group_vars/all.yml` I have the correct IP for the host that ansible should use to connect. I have to do so, as I do not have the IP's beforehand. Prior to running the role described below, I run a role that creates the servers and only after that I have the IP's.

This is my `playbook.yml`:

```
- name: do_something
  hosts: 
    - "{{ NETWORK.IP }}"
  roles:
    - my_role
```

and the file`group_vars/all.yml` looks like this:

```
NETWORK:
    IP: 10.0.0.1
```

and when I execute I get:

```
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml
...
ERROR! The field 'hosts' has an invalid value, which includes an undefined variable. The error was: 'NETWORK' is undefined

The error appears to be in 'playbook.yml': line X, column Y, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
```

**I tried** using different things such as

- in an earlier task on localhost using the set_facts module to set the variable
- using the gather_facts in the playbook
- using vars_file: group_vars/all.yml

**Is it even possible to do like that? What am I doing wrong?**

---

When I do something like this in the playbook:

```
- name:
  do_something2  hosts:
    - LOCALHOST
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        MY_HOST: "{{ NETWORK.IP }}"
```

it is working. So I guess it has something to do with the 'all.yml' as the LOCALHOST is defined in a group. But `all.yml` should be possible to use even if the host is not defined in a group right?

---

**Additional information**:
This is the output of `ansible --version`:

```
ansible [core 2.13.3]
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['SOME_PATH', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = SOME_PATH
  ansible collection location = SOME_PATH
  executable location = SOME_PATH
  python version = 3.10.8 (main, Oct 19 2022, 07:46:20) [GCC]
  jinja version = 3.1.2
  libyaml = True
```

and I'm running it on openSUSE Leap

edit: added the description as of why I need to have it set dynamically (because I create the servers in an earlier role).

Comment: You should rather use an inventory. Why set the ip in a group_vars? You're creating a 'chicken/egg' problem, because Ansible can't connect to the host you have setup in your group vars.

Comment: The problem is that i don't know the IP of the host at that point of time. In a first step i create the host with the proxmox module and then i want to directly provision it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% of what you're trying to accomplish here, but as Kevin said, you should use an inventory for this. I never used group_vars/all.yml. Just create an inventory directory where your playbook is located, then create an inventory or hosts files with your host name and group if you have one:

inventory/hosts:

```
[dev]
host1
host2
```

Then if you want to add the network IP for each host, you should put it in your host_vars directory, not on the group_vars. Create a host_vars directory with different files for each host. They need to have the same name as your host:

inventory/host_vars/host1.yml

```
ansible_host: 10.10.10.10
```

Then if you have common variables that'll be used by differents hosts, you can create a file named by the group on the group_vars directory:

inventory/group_vars/dev.yml:

```
gateway_ip: 10.10.10.1
```

Once everything is created it is really easy to manage. If there are specific hosts you need to add, just put them in a group on your hosts.yml file.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The problem is that I do not "know" the IP at that point of time. I have the servers in the inventory already, but I do not have the IP's. This is because I create them ealier in the playbook.

Answer (score 0):

So for anyone having a similiar problem, my solution was do have a role on the localhost and changing the inventory file. Here is the code that I used:

```
- name : Adding created hosts to inventory
  lineinfile:
    path: "inventory.yml"
    insertafter: "{{ item.NAME }}"
    regexp: '^{{ item.NAME }}'
    line: "          ansible_ssh_host: {{ item.IP }}"
  loop: "{{ network }}"

- meta: refresh_inventory
```

With this I'm able to parse the configuration file `all.yml` and then assign each host their ip.